# Can the background color of Text Editor be changed in Tableau?

Tags: colors, text-editor, tableau-api

I do have a dark themed tableau dashboard where the fonts will be white in color. whenever I try to edit the text in textbox, the editor pops with white as its background color (font color is also white so I cant see the text). Is there any option that I can change the background color of the text editor ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you post a screenshot? When I change the color I get the same matching color in the text boxes:

[image]

Comment: Yea buddy, changing Textbox's background color to dark helps me. Figured on my own and thanks for your answer too...